# Can more than one parameter be there for onPostExecute() method of AsyncTask?

Tags: java, android, kotlin

i have a question about AsyncTask. I know that i can pass 1 or more parameter to "doInBackground" Method but how can i return more than one value to the "onPostExecute" Method, becauce i what to download data from two diffrent pages and the result back to Main Thread. I know how to return the data to Main Thread (with an Interface) but dont get it how to pass the results of the download to the postExecute

Comment: You can pass a single `Class` as a `Type`, but that Class can contain multiple things.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can easily incapsulate two response in one object if they is different and use this new class as Result type for [AsyncTask](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html#executeOnExecutor%28java.util.concurrent.Executor,%20Params...%29) (e.g. `AsyncTask<URL, Void, MyCompositeType`).

If they have the same type or same interface you can use an ArrayList (e.g. `AsyncTask<URL, Void, Arraylist<Response>>`).

You have to build the data in `doInBackground` method.